# How to partition a query and load only a few properties with Linq to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following POCOs:

```
public Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdOwner { get; set; }
    public int IdDependency { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public Owner Owner { get; set; } 
    public Dependency Dependency { get; set; }
}

public Owner 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other attributes
}

public Dependency 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other attributes
}
```

I want to return a `List` of Tickets that has only `Owner Name` and `Dependency Name`. The problem is, i will write a `where` with `Owner` if in my filter i pass the `OwnerId`, and the same to `Dependency`. Look to my filter:

```
public List<Ticket> SelectTickets(string SerialNumber, int IdOwner, int IdDependency)
{
    IQueryble<Ticket> query = context.Tickets.Where(t => t.SerialNumber == SerialNumber);

    if (IdOwner != 0)
    {
        query = query.Where( ?? );
    }

    if (IdDependency!= 0)
    {
        query = query.Where( ?? );
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I can't understand. What exactly do you want to do? Do you want a projection after `where`?

Answer (score 0):

That would make sense, if i understood what you mean.

```
        public Ticket
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int OwnerId{ get; set; }
            public int DependencyId { get; set; }
            public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

            public Owner Owner { get; set; } 
            public Dependency Dependency { get; set; }
        }

        public Owner 
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Ticket> Tickets {get;set;}
        }

        public Dependency 
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Ticket> Tickets {get;set;}
        }
        public List<Ticket> SelectTickets(string serialNumber, int ownerId, int dependencyId)
        {
            return context.Tickets.Where(t => t.SerialNumber == serialNumber && t.OwnerId == ownerId && t.DependencyId == dependencyId).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: I think that you miss this part "I want to return a List of Tickets that has only Owner Name and Dependency Name". With you query, i will return the entire Ticket with the entire Owner and Dependency, not only the attributes that i said.

Answer (score 0):

Use the select statement.

```
query = query.Select(t => new Ticket { 
    Owner = new Owner {Name = t.Owner.Name}, 
    Dependency = new Dependency  {Name = t.Dependency.Name}
}); 
return query.ToList();
```

However, it seems that in this case you would not want to return a Ticket but some other object such as TicketSummary

```
public class TicketSummary {
    public OwnerName {get;set;}
    public DependencyName {get;set;}
}
```

Then you would have

```
query = query.Select(t => new TicketSummary { 
    OwnerName = t.Owner.Name, 
    DependencyName = t.Dependency.Name
}); 
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: With the first query I got the following error: The entity or complex type 'Model.Ticket' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: There is a way to return the Ticket with only the attributes that i said without creating a new class (TicketSummary)?

Answer (score 0):

You could project your resulting query to any format you like AFTER filtering it.

Does replacing the return statement with this work for you or do you have more complex requirements I did not fully understand?

```
return query.Select(t => new Ticket() {
    Owner = t.Owner,
    Dependency = t.Dependency;
}.ToList();
```

Comment: I got the following error: The entity or complex type 'Model.Ticket' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: You need to create a type tailored to the model representation of your database ticket. The problem is that a Ticket represents raw data from your database. You should create a new class TicketRelations that reprensents what a ticket's dependency and owner means from your model's perpective. I don't know what an object with these two could actually reprensent though. It seems to lack cohesion. Depending on what you wish to use this stripped down ticket for, maybe you could have the OwnerName and DependencyName properties on this new type instead of object refernces to better abstract your DAL?

Comment: Ok, i understood that Ticket is a raw data from my DB, but why i cannot use this raw data(new Ticket)? Because when i do a simple select i return a Ticket, but in this case i cannot?